# Mock.patch not reset between django test runs

Tags: django

I have 2 tests which are testing a view that makes a call to an external module. I've mocked it with `mock.patch`. I'm calling the view by using django's test client.

The first test (a test for 404 being returned) completes successfully and the correct mock is called.

When the second test runs, everything runs as normal, but the mock that the code-under-test has access to is the mock from the previous test.

You can see in this example https://dpaste.de/7zT8 that the ids in the test output are incorrect (around line 91).

Where is this getting cached? My initial thought was that the import of the main module is somehow cached between test runs due to urlconf stuff. Tracing through the source code, I couldn't find that as the case.

**Expected**: Both tests pass.

**Actual**: Second test fails due to stale mocked import.

If I comment out the 404 test, the other test passes.
The view is registered in the url conf as the string-y version `'repos.views.github_webhook'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not fully understand what causes the exact behaviour you are seeing, especially not why the mock is seemingly working correctly in the first test. But according to the mock docs, you should patch in the namespace under test, i.e. `patch("views.tasks")`.

http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#where-to-patch

Comment: Thanks so much. This fixes the problem! Would love to know why though.